# jQuery smooth scroll in Japanese

Tags: jquery, cjk

[in this page](https://denryoku-gas.jp/utility/hokkaido) (in Japanese), the links use jQuery to make a smooth transition towards the ID they're referenced to, but as it is using Japanese characters (`SEOwise`), it does not work.

```js
// Smooth scroll
    
    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
            if (target.length) {
                $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top - 200
                }, 1000);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sommaire bullets" role="navigation">
  <ol>
    <li><a href="#北海道エリアで選べる電力会社">北海道エリアで選べる電力会社</a></li>
    <li><a href="#北海道エリア電力会社・電気料金">北海道エリアの電力会社と電気料金プラン</a></li>
  </ol>
</div> 

<h2 id="北海道エリアで選べる電力会社">北海道エリアで選べる電力会社</h2>
<h2 id="北海道エリア電力会社・電気料金">北海道エリアの電力会社と電気料金プラン</h2>
```

If I change the `href` and the ID to any Latin-based wording, it works as expected.

Is there any way I can make jQuery work with the Japanese characters?

Comment: Can you please show your html and JS?

Comment: You got snippets of code on the edit. But you can go to the link I put initially where all the code is online and where you can check everything :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to decode `this.hash` first. This can be done using `decodeURIComponent()`.

This should work:

```js
// Smooth scroll
    
    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var target = $(decodeURIComponent(this.hash));
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
            if (target.length) {
                $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top - 200
                }, 1000);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sommaire bullets" role="navigation">
  <ol>
    <li><a href="#北海道エリアで選べる電力会社">北海道エリアで選べる電力会社</a></li>
    <li><a href="#北海道エリア電力会社・電気料金">北海道エリアの電力会社と電気料金プラン</a></li>
  </ol>
</div> 

<h2 id="北海道エリアで選べる電力会社">北海道エリアで選べる電力会社</h2>
<h2 id="北海道エリア電力会社・電気料金">北海道エリアの電力会社と電気料金プラン</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Smooth scroll
    
    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
   
   $('body, html').stop().animate({
                    'scrollTop': $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
                }, 980);
                
                return false;
            
            
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sommaire bullets" role="navigation">
  <ol>
    <li><a href="#北海道エリアで選べる電力会社">北海道エリアで選べる電力会社</a></li>
    <li><a href="#北海道エリア電力会社・電気料金">北海道エリアの電力会社と電気料金プラン</a></li>
  </ol>
</div> 
<div style="height:500px; width:100%;"></div>
<h2 id="北海道エリアで選べる電力会社">北海道エリアで選べる電力会社</h2>
<div style="height:500px; width:100%;"></div>
<h2 id="北海道エリア電力会社・電気料金">北海道エリアの電力会社と電気料金プラン</h2>
```

Sorry I am not sure what is your code means, but I've simplified for you.

Comment: thx a lot! It has been difficult to track down for me too, as I don't understand japanese either!